# selectInput and plot render

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

Welcome.

I tried to show plots using selectInput.
I set the selectInput with name, title, options.
In main i add six plot...

How to make it work ? 
There is no error and all plots is showing on one page.

.ui

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Japan TeleCOM"),

    includeCSS("styles.css"),
    #
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Subscribers Market Share in Japan for Mobile Prepaid and Postpaid market and its' competition in 2000-2013"),

    sidebarPanel
    (

      selectInput("statename", "Select plot", c("plotOne", "plotTwo", "plotThree", "plot4th", "plot5th", "plot6th"), selected = "PlotOne")

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distrisbution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plotOne"),
      plotOutput("plotTwo"),
      plotOutput("plotThree"),
      plotOutput("plot4th"),
      plotOutput("plot5th"),
      plotOutput("plot6th")
    )


))
```

.server (two plots, other have semi code)

```
ibrary(shiny)
library(xlsx) # to read excel files
library(ggplot2) # to plot
library(scales) # to describe values on the plot 2,000,000 instead of 2000000

dataFromExcel <- read.xlsx(file="japan_telecom_dane.xlsx", sheetIndex=1,header=TRUE)
dataFromExcel2 <- read.xlsx(file="japan_telecom_dane_perc.xlsx", sheetIndex=1,header=TRUE)
###FIRST PLOT#####

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df <- dataFromExcel
  df2 <- dataFromExcel2

  output$plotOne <- renderPlot({

    df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    x <- df$Date # first column with Date
    y <- df[ , 2:length(df)] # (all columns from df without the first one, the first column was x = Date)
    plotGgplot <- ggplot() +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$nttdocomo_prepaid, color=" nttdocomo_prepaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$nttdocomo_postpaid, color=" nttdocomo_postpaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$softbank_prepaid, color=" softbank_prepaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$softbank_postpaid, color=" softbank_postpaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$kddi_prepaid, color=" kddi_prepaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$kddi_postpaid, color=" kddi_postpaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      ylab('Number of Subscribers') +
      xlab('Year') +
      scale_y_continuous ( labels = comma, breaks = seq(from=0,to=190000000,by=5000000)) +
      ggtitle("Subscribers in Japan for main privider and its' competition in 2000-2013") +
      theme(plot.title=element_text(size=8, face="bold",
                                    hjust = 0.5),
            axis.title=element_text(size=8))
    plotGgplot
  })

  #####Second PLOT######

  output$plotTwo <- renderPlot({

    df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    x <- df$Date # first column with Date
    y <- df[ , 2:length(df)] # (all columns from df without the first one, the first column was x = Date)
    plotGgplot <- ggplot() +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$nttdocomo_postpaid, color=" nttdocomo_postpaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$softbank_postpaid, color=" softbank_postpaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y$kddi_postpaid, color=" kddi_postpaid "), linetype = 1, size = 1.6) +
      ylab('Number of Subscribers') +
      xlab('Year') +
      scale_y_continuous ( labels = comma, breaks = seq(from=0,to=190000000,by=20000)) +
      ggtitle("Subscribers in Japan for main privider and its' competition in 2000-2013") +
      theme(plot.title=element_text(size=8, face="bold",
                                    hjust = 0.5),
            axis.title=element_text(size=8))
    plotGgplot
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to plot only one of the ggplot at the time based on the value of the selectInput.

You can do this with:

UI.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("SO Test"),
  titlePanel("Test"),
  # Your input selection
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("plotnumber", "Select plot", c("Bubble", "Line"), selected = "Bubble")
  ),
  # Show the selected plot
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("whichplot")
  )
))
```

and SERVER.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2) 
library(scales)     

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #Random dataframe
  df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))

  # If conditions determining which plot should be used
  output$whichplot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$plotnumber == 'Bubble'){
      G = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
        geom_point()
    }
    if(input$plotnumber == 'Line'){
      G = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
        geom_line()
    }
    G
  })    

})
```